# How to open OneDrive files from WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file-io, onedrive

When I try to open OneDrive file paths from a WPF application I get the following error when using `File.ReadAllText(filename);`:

`The file cannot be accessed by the system.`

Despite trying to check for read permissions explicitly:

```
private static bool HasReadPermissions(string filename)
{
    FileSystemSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(filename);
    var rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    var currentUser = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
    {
        if (!currentUser.IsInRole(rule.IdentityReference.Value) || (rule.FileSystemRights & (FileSystemRights.ReadData | FileSystemRights.Read)) == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any way to check for OneDrive permissions or to detect whether a file is a OneDrive file or to actually open OneDrive files in a WPF application? I think the fact that this file is available online-only may be the issue; is there a way to detect online-only files in WPF or Windows desktop apps?

Comment: Does this help?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/25/opening-files-from-skydrive-using-net.aspx

Comment: Could you provide an example path?

Answer (score 1):

This question is relatively old and so this answer is mainly for readers who find it by searching.

You can tell if a file is an online-only OneDrive file in desktop apps. Just check the file attributes and if offline attribute is attached, the file would be online-only OneDrive file. The following is the sample method:

```
public static bool IsFileAvailable(string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        return false;

    var attributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);

    Debug.WriteLine(attributes);
    // Available online-only: Hidden, System, Archive, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Offline
    // Available offline: Archive

    return !attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Offline);
}
```

Offline attribute does not directly indicate that the file is online-only OneDrive file but the data of the file is not immediately available and I think it is what you want to know.